# Relation between left and right invariant vector fields.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

What I'm trying to show:

Let $Y$ be a vector field on a Lie group $G$. If $G$ is connected and $[X,Y]=0$ for all left invariant vector field $X$, then $Y$ is right invariant.

I thought I could prove it using only the relations between left and right invariant vector fields, but I failed. I realized I wasn't using the connectedness of $G$. I'm having difficulty in understanding what role plays the connectedness of $G$.

Comment: Related: [Showing that left invariant vector fields commute with right invariant vector fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295758/showing-that-left-invariant-vector-fields-commute-with-right-invariant-vector-fi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We must remember two things :

1. Two vector fields $X,Y$, commute iff there flows commute, iff $Y$ is invariant by the flow of $X$.
2. The flow of the *left* invariant vector field $X$ is the *right* translation by $\exp t X(e)$, where $X(e)$ is the value at $e$ of $X$.

From this, if $Y$ commute with evry left invariant vector field, it is invariant by the right translation by  $g= \exp   X $ for $X$ in the Lie algebra of $G$.

Now, if the group $G$ is *connected*, it is generated by elements of the form $\exp X$, and the result follows.